# Finding text in a string that matches a pattern along with the parts of it that don't

Tags: regex, parsing, python-2.7

I want to parse strings that may contain xml-/html-like mark-up tags. However I want to avoid using third-party modules like `lxml` or `beautifulsoup` because the tags are extremely simple, consisting of only a name and they can't overlap, be nested, nor have additional attributes.

For these reasons I've been attempting to do it using only the built-in `re` module and regular expressions.

This is what I've tried so far:

```
import re

pattern = r'<(?P<tag>\w+)>(?P<content>.+)</(?P=tag)>'
my_str = ("Here's some <first>sample stuff</first> in the "
          "<second>middle</second> of some other text.")
print re.findall(pattern, my_str)
```

Results:

```
[('first', 'sample stuff'), ('second', 'middle')]
```

This is fine, it gives me all the tags matched and information about them, but I also need to know about the text which didn't match the pattern since it needs to be processed (in the order found), too — so the next thing I tried was using the module's `split()` function as shown below to divide the string up into both tagged and untagged sections:

```
print re.split(pattern, my_str)
```

Results:

```
["Here's some ", 'first', 'sample stuff', ' in the ', 'second', 'middle',
 ' of some other text.']
```

This looks promising in the sense that the results now include everything in the string — both the parts that matched the pattern as well as those that didn't — but it's difficult telling which is what in the resulting simple list of strings that it returns.

So my question is can these deficiencies be fixed and how (without resorting to some additional third-party module).

If I could get something as simple as the following, where the info for any tagged content was easily distinguishable, it would be ideal:

```
["Here's some ", ('first', 'sample stuff'), ' in the ', ('second', 'middle'),
 ' of some other text.']
```

Comment: What's the desired output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here something fairly simple that appears to work. It uses `re.findall()` and a slightly modified version of the regex suggested by Rawing that also captures non-tag text, if any, preceding the tag.

I've expanded the number of strings tested to include all the edge cases I could think of. The slight modification to Rawing's regex was changing `(?P<content>.+)` to `(?P<content>.*)` so empty constructs like `'<abc></abc>'` would also be considered valid tags.

```
from __future__ import print_function
import re

pattern = r'(?P<text>.*?)(?:<(?P<tag>\w+)>(?P<content>.*)</(?P=tag)>|$)'

testcases = [ "Here's some <first>sample stuff</first> in the "
                "<second>middle</second> of some other text.",
              "<first>sample stuff</first> in the "
                "<second>middle</second> of some other text.",
              "Here's some <first>sample stuff</first> in the "
                "<second>middle</second>",
              "<first>sample stuff</first> in the <second>middle</second>",
              "Here's some ",
              "<first>sample stuff</first>",
              "<first></first>",
]

for my_str in testcases:
    print(' my_str: {!r}'.format(my_str))
    # nitty-gritty of conversion from match objects to list
    results = []
    for text, tag, content in re.findall(pattern, my_str):
        if text: results.append(text)
        if tag: results.append((tag, content))
    print('results: {}\n'.format(results))
```

Output:

```
 my_str: "Here's some <first>sample stuff</first> in the <second>middle</second> of some other text."
results: ["Here's some ", ('first', 'sample stuff'), ' in the ', ('second', 'middle'), ' of some other text.']

 my_str: '<first>sample stuff</first> in the <second>middle</second> of some other text.'
results: [('first', 'sample stuff'), ' in the ', ('second', 'middle'), ' of some other text.']

 my_str: "Here's some <first>sample stuff</first> in the <second>middle</second>"
results: ["Here's some ", ('first', 'sample stuff'), ' in the ', ('second', 'middle')]

 my_str: '<first>sample stuff</first> in the <second>middle</second>'
results: [('first', 'sample stuff'), ' in the ', ('second', 'middle')]

 my_str: "Here's some "
results: ["Here's some "]

 my_str: '<first>sample stuff</first>'
results: [('first', 'sample stuff')]

 my_str: '<first></first>'
results: [('first', '')]
```

Answer (score 3):

How about the [ElementTree](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html) module? It's builtin so no third party deps and it will handle that very easily.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree as ET

data = ("Here's some <first>sample stuff</first> in the "
        "<second>middle</second> of some other text.")

root = ET.fromstring('<x>%s</x>' % data)

# First block of text (before any tags)
print(root.text)

for child in root:
    # Tag, and text within tag
    print((child.tag, child.text))
    # Next block of text outside tags
    print(child.tail)
```

And the output:

```
Here's some
('first', 'sample stuff')
 in the
('second', 'middle')
 of the other text.
```

It would be easy to rearrange this to output a list if that is what you need, or as a generator:

```
def parse(data):
    root = ET.fromstring('<x>%s</x>' % data)
    yield root.text
    for child in root:
        yield (child.tag, child.text)
        yield child.tail
```

Regarding the comment on YAGNI, the statment is *"Always implement things when you actually need them, never when you just foresee that you need them."* And the key word there is "implement".  You are not implementing an xml parser, merely using one.  I fully agree with the principle as it applies to your own code, but it cannot apply to every library you use, or where would it stop?  Python contains many functions that you are not going to use, so does that mean you should compile your own python with those functions stripped out?  The YAGNI principle is an excellent approach to writing code, but not to using other people's code.  In fact, if you follow the reasoning behind the principle, you should use a prebuilt library rather than writing your own.  The reasoning is given:

- *You save time*, because you avoid writing code that you turn out not to need.
- *Your code is better*, because you avoid polluting it with 'guesses' that turn out to be more or less wrong but stick around anyway.

So to save time, avoid writing code when you could use code that is already written.  To make your code better, avoid polluting it with code duplicating existing functionality.

Also consider that writing you own mini-xml parser to strip out unused code and (presumably) improve performance could easily be seen as [Premature Optimization](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?PrematureOptimization)

Comment: This may work although I have to wrap the whole string in an outer tag first, e.q. `my_xml = '<data>' + my_str + '</data>'`.

Comment: Yes, but wrapping it is a one liner, easy. Since you're parsing xml, you should use a tool for parsing xml. Regular expressions will get very complicated very quickly and, as you've discovered, are quite hard to get right and debug in the first place. Why go through that when you can use a builtin tool that does exactly what you need.

Comment: Yes, having to wrap it isn't a problem. The thing is it's _not_ xml, it's much simpler and shouldn't need a full-blown xml parser along with its "well-formedness rules". That said, one advantage to using one anyway is that it'd likely facilitate adding more advanced features, such as tag attributes, in the future, should it become necessary. However it seem easier could wait and switch to one when (and if) it ever becomes justifiable.

Comment: I had a very similar problem a while ago, something that was basically text containing xml tags. It was still much easier to just use an existing xml parser than try to write my own. It also wasn't long before I found that I did actually need nested tags and attributes, and that came at no extra cost.  Anyway,  where's the loss in using a full blown parser? It is well tested, and probably more robust and efficient than your own implementation. Also somebody has already thought about the obscure corner cases that you will need to identify and test.

Comment: I understand the points you make, but don't want to over-engineer things (coincidentally I was recently reading about YagNi ([You Aren't Gonna Need It](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?YouArentGonnaNeedIt)) which seems contrary to your arguments. However, I might be persuaded if you could show me how to use ElementTree to produce the desired results in your answer, so I can compare it to my own using `re.findall()` and a relatively simple `for` loop to do it.

Comment: I have updated my answer with a complete solution, and also commented on the application of YagNI.

Answer (score 2):

You could use `finditer` and do the split manually based on `span`, something like this (DISCLAIMER: boundary cases untested!):

```
def split_and_keep(pattern, my_str):
    index = 0
    for match in re.finditer(pattern, my_str):
        span = match.span()
        if span[0] > index:
            yield my_str[index:span[0]]
        index = span[1]
        yield match.groupdict()
    left = my_str[index:]
    if left:
        yield left
```

which would give

```
>>> for part in split_and_keep(pattern, my_str):
...     print(repr(part))
...     
"Here's some "
{'content': 'sample stuff', 'tag': 'first'}
' in the '
{'content': 'middle', 'tag': 'second'}
' of some other text.'
```

Here you'd tell matches and non-matches apart by type, but obviously you could tweak it into something saner.

Comment: This appears to work OK, although it seems like the generator is doing a lot of parsing itself -- in fact I considered doing something similar to this (using match object `start`, `end`, and `span` attributes) before asking my question, but that seems to almost defeat the purpose of using a reg-exp. Seems like there ought to be a way to expand the pattern so that it would include any text before and/or after the part that matches the tag itself -- so that it would end up in its own match object.

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of the [start() and end() functions](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.start).

```
last_match= 0
for match in re.finditer(pattern, my_str):
    print 'this text matched:', match.group()
    print "this text didn't:", my_str[last_match:match.start()]
    last_match= match.end()
print 'remaining text:', my_str[last_match:]
```

Comment: Your answer is similar to @DSM's, however I'm somwhat reluctant to go this route -- see my comment under his answer for why.

Comment: I'm not sure what the point is, but if you want to capture the text between tags, you can use this pattern: `(?P<text>.*?)(?:<(?P<tag>\w+)>(?P<content>.+)</(?P=tag)>|$)`. This will, however, produce an empty match at the end of the text, see [demo](https://regex101.com/r/aB7lF1/1).

Comment: Empty matches wouldn't be an issue. Looks like your modification to the regex might work with `re.finall()`. Could it be incorporated into your answer based on `re.finditer()`?